# HTML/CSS Text Aligning

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am formally new to Web Development and it seems I'm in quite a pickle. I'm creating a Garry's Mod loading screen and I need help the text aligning with a gap between both wraps.

This is what it's suppose to look like:
[☻](http://potatofactory.ta0soft.com/Capture.JPG)[image]

And its turns out pictures are boring so here is a link to the live page:
[☻](http://potatofactory.ta0soft.com/?id=76561198074240735)

The current html is:

```
<table width="46%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span class="TitleStyle">
                <div class="LoadEnhancment">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                        <img src="<?php echo $steamUser->getMediumAvatarUrl() ?>"/><br />
                        <?php echo "Welcome <span class='persona'>" . $nickname . "</span>"; ?><hr />
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
            </span>
            <span class="VolTx1">
                Hello.<br />
                This is a new line.
            </span>
            <span class="VolBlk">
            </span>
            <span class="VolTx2">
                Hello.
            </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.VolTx1 {
    font-family: DetailedFont;
    font-size: 30;
    color: white;
    margin: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
.VolBlk {
    height: 800px;
    width: 200px
}
.VolTx2 {
    font-family: DetailedFont;
    font-size: 30;
    color: white;
    margin: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: dont use table for layout

Comment: Side note, highly recommend going through this as someone new to front-end development: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web (I believe it's free)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this html

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="VolTx1">
   Hello.<br />
    This is a new line.
   </div>
   <div class="VolBlk"></div>
   <div class="VolTx1">
       Hello.
   </div>
   <br class="clear">
</div>
```

and css

```
.wrapper {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.VolTx1 {
float:left;
width:200px;
padding:50px;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;
font-family: DetailedFont;
}
.VolBlk {
float: left;
width: 136px;
margin: 0 32px;
}
.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

instead of

```
<span class="VolTx1">
Hello.<br />
This is a new line.
</span>
<span class="VolBlk">
</span>
<span class="VolTx2">
Hello.
</span>
```

And I recommend do not use tables in that case.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your DOCTYPE not proper. It is  Remove 5 from html5

Update your doctype and than refine your whole code according to new standard.

Comment: The web server is weird, if I do that every goes white :\